# Setting Environment variables in Spark Cluster Mode

Tags: apache-spark, environment-variables, hadoop-yarn

I was going through this [Apache Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables), and it mentions that:

> When running Spark on YARN in `cluster` mode, environment variables
>   need to be set using the
>   `spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName]` property in your
>   `conf/spark-defaults.conf` file.

I am running my EMR cluster on AWS data pipeline. I wanted to know that where do I have to edit this conf file. Also, if I create my own custom conf file, and specify it as part of `--configurations` (in the spark-submit), will it solve my use-case?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it, is the following: (The tricky part is that you might need to setup the environment variables on both executor and driver parameters)

```
spark-submit   \
 --driver-memory 2g \
 --executor-memory 4g \
 --conf spark.executor.instances=4 \
 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-DENV_KEY=ENV_VALUE" \
 --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-DENV_KEY=ENV_VALUE" \
 --master yarn \
 --deploy-mode cluster\
 --class com.industry.class.name \
   assembly-jar.jar
```

I have tested it in EMR and client mode but should work on cluster mode as well.

Comment: It should be a JVM property in this case, not an environment variable? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You are right. My answer covers the case for the JVM properties. In this case, the `spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName]` and  `spark.executorEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName]` should be used for the driver and executors, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference you could directly pass the environment variable when creating the EMR cluster using the Configurations parameter as described in the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html).

Specifically, the `spark-defaults` file can be modified by passing a configuration JSON as follows:

```
{
    'Classification': 'spark-defaults',
    'Properties': {
        'spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName]' = 'some_value',
        'spark.executorEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName]': 'some_other_value'
    }
},
```

Where `spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName]` would be used to pass a variable in cluster mode using YARN ([here](http://spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.%5BEnvironmentVariableName%5D)). And `spark.executorEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName]` to pass a variable to the executor process ([here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/configuration.html#runtime-environment)).